# Monitoring executable file

Tags: monitoring, exe, monitor, executable-format

I have a program I purchased several years ago, the last years when I install a new windows I was call my software programmer to install it again on my PC.
Now I can't find this guy and want to open the program, so I want to know which files is needed to open my exe file and if any keys to the register should I add, I think it's monitoring to check what I should add.

anything like this I can use to know.
P.S: I have the exe file and tried to open it, it asking for some files and already added to the system32, now it not asking for anything but close the program without opening even the 1st screen.

Comment: YMMV http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 will show you failed access attempts with the correct set of filters

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get the static AND dynamic dependencies. The Dynamic dependencies are shown when you use this tool in the so called "profiling mode".